# Why do i get wrong output time when I query time from timezonedb (python)

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, timezonedb

I am trying to give date(indate, inmonth) and time(intime) from a timezone(fromtz), then request for time in another timezone(totz) using timezonedb api

```
indate = args[0]
inmonth=args[1]
intime=args[2]
fromtz=args[3]
totz=args[4]

inyear = datetime.now().year

print(str(indate)+'/'+str(inmonth)+'/'+str(inyear)+' '+str(intime))
dt_obj = datetime.strptime(str(indate)+'/'+str(inmonth)+'/'+str(inyear)+' '+str(intime),'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

millisec = dt_obj.timestamp() * 1000
url="http://api.timezonedb.com/v2.1/convert-time-zone?key="+API_KEY+"&format=json&from="+fromtz+"&to="+totz+"&time="+str(int(millisec))

response = requests.get(url)
jsonoutput = json.loads(response.text)
timeoutputms = jsonoutput["toTimestamp"]
outputdt = datetime.fromtimestamp(timeoutputms/1000).strftime('%d/%m %H:%M')
```

Test 1:

> Input - 30 01 00:00 CST GMT

> Output - 30/01 00:00 CST

> Correct output must be - 30/01 06:00 CST

Test 2:

> Input - 30 01 00:00 GMT CST

> Output - 29/01 23:59 CST

> Correct output must be - 29/01 18:00 CST

JSON response: {'status': 'OK', 'message': '', 'fromZoneName': 'Europe/Jersey', 'fromAbbreviation': 'GMT', 'fromTimestamp': 1611945000000, 'toZoneName': 'America/North_Dakota/Beulah', 'toAbbreviation': 'CST', 'toTimestamp': 1611944978400, 'offset': -21600}

Comment: [CST is ambiguous](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/) - there are at least three of them... better stick to [IANA names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Answer (score 0):

Your query works in principle if you use proper time zone names (as listed in [timezonedb docs](https://timezonedb.com/time-zones)). Unambiguous abbreviations such as GMT or UTC should work as well.

**Ex:**

```
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.tz import gettz

myZone, toZone = "Europe/London", "America/New_York"

# localize to my tz, set microsecs zero
now = datetime.now(gettz(myZone)).replace(microsecond=0)
msec = now.timestamp()*1000

# now query timezonedb
url = f"http://api.timezonedb.com/v2.1/convert-time-zone?key={API_Key}&format=json&from={myZone}&to={toZone}&time={int(msec)}"
response = requests.get(url)
jsonoutput = json.loads(response.text)
timeoutputms = jsonoutput["toTimestamp"]

# ...and convert back to Python datetime for sanity-check
now_toZone = datetime.fromtimestamp(timeoutputms/1000, gettz(toZone))

print(f"input: {now}\noutput: {now_toZone}\ndiff: {(now_toZone-now).total_seconds()} s")
# input: 2021-02-02 14:37:02+00:00
# output: 2021-02-02 09:36:44-05:00
# diff: -18.0 s
```

Interestingly, input and output are off by ~18s for my test query. Not sure where that comes from but off-topic here.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar to this. Normally new launch announcements are made in timezone codes like EST and I want to get it converted to the person's local timezone. A lot of people don't know which country the timezone belongs to, I checked for EST to IST too but it doesn't work.

Comment: @DeadPool: if you consider my comment under your question, if you *only* have the abbreviated tz name, in many cases, you simply have to *guess* the actual time zone. Not the kind of approach you normally want to have as a programmer ;-)

Comment: but then how do websites like savvytime convert time.. I want a way to convert time zone instead of going to website everytime. they have handled the conversion from est to gmt properly.

Comment: @DeadPool: well *some* abbreviations are unambiguous and there's also your IP address if local time is needed. If you just need to convert tz in Python, you have plenty of options, see packages zoneinfo, dateutil, pytz etc.